# Pytorch profiler with scheduler prints unwanted message at step

Tags: python, pytorch, profiler

I am trying to learn how to use the Pytorch profiler API to measure the difference in performance when training a model using different methods. In the dedicated [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html), there is one part where they show how to do just that using the "schedule" parameter of the profiler.

My problem is that when I want to use it in my code, calling step the first "wait" times prints a message

> [W kineto_shim.cpp:337] Profiler is not initialized: skipping step() invocation

Since I want my profiler to sleep most of the time, my "wait" value is quite high so it pollutes my terminal with a bunch of those lines until the profiler is actually executed for the first time

How can I get rid of it ?

Here's a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem

```py
import torch
from torch.profiler import profile, record_function, ProfilerActivity

with profile(
        activities=[torch.profiler.ProfilerActivity.CUDA],
        schedule=torch.profiler.schedule(wait=15, warmup=1, active=4),        
        profile_memory=False,
        record_shapes=True,
        with_stack=True,
    ) as prof:
        for _ in range(20):
            y = torch.randn(1).cuda() + torch.randn(1).cuda()
            prof.step()
            

print(prof.key_averages())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just recently fixed/added in a [pull request](https://github.com/pytorch/kineto/issues/726)

now you can set the env variable `KINETO_LOG_LEVEL`.
For example in a bash script: `export KINETO_LOG_LEVEL=3`

The levels according to the source code are:

```cpp
enum LoggerOutputType {
  VERBOSE = 0,
  INFO = 1,
  WARNING = 2,
  ERROR = 3,
  STAGE = 4,
  ENUM_COUNT = 5
};
```

Thats atleast how it should work, according to [this issue](https://github.com/pytorch/kineto/issues/726#issuecomment-1601936313) the changes for the log level have not been merged yet